# How to update (date) in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

Hello so basically I want to update a date in MySQL but to make the thing done in php form like:

```
<?php
  $sql = "UPDATE users 
            set expire_date=CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 30 DAY 
          WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['user_email'] . "'";
?>
```

Sorry If I described my question weirdly but Its important for my project, any help appreciated!

Comment: So you have an update query... now what is the problem ??

Comment: Did you do anything other than place a query into a string variable. Because its not magic, you have to connect to a database and issue a query to be executed on that database

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, it don't update the date, I want to get the correct php code to do that..

Comment: Did you connect to the PHP Session? `session_start()` in this code?

Comment: _"Sorry If I described my question weirdly but Its important for my project"_ - well all the more reason then that you should put some more effort in giving us an _understandable_ problem description.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the [PHP PDO Manual pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) And then read [this useful tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) to help it all make sense

Comment: Hey RiggsFolly, I actually did that too, and also:  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                echo "<script>alert('Date Updated!')</script>";
             
            } did that code everything works except the date won't change.

Comment: _"I want to get the correct php code to do that"_ - looks like your problem is actually much more the correct _MySQL_ syntax to use in that place of your statement ... so: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Ok so first in order to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) <<-- Specially this one

Comment: Hey CBroe, My question is very clear, and not just for my project for every users In SO, Like why I have to read a whole documentation to find out what is the right code to put !?, Like I don't Understand just give me the code and question answered ...

Comment: You have asked a few question, all have been down voted because they are very badly asked. If you want our help you have to make SOME EFFORT to 1) ask a question. 2) Provide us with enough information about what you have done and the result you are attempting to achieve. As to your "Just give me an answer" attitude, we are not paid by you so are not obliged to do your work for you

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: _"Like why I have to read a whole documentation to find out what is the right code to put !?"_ - ...because that's what documentations are for? Stackoverflow isn't a replacement for doing your own research. Have a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to get an understanding of what we expect that you have done before asking.

Comment: Hey y'all thanks, but none of you're suggestions or comments was helpful, And I do what I like, I don't need to learn how to ask question, I just got my answer!

Comment: The "answer" will only give something like [this](https://onlinephp.io/c/d48bc) . So ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = " $sql = "UPDATE users 
            set expire_date=DATE_ADD(`date` , INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['user_email'] . "'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: It would be worth using parameter binding - depending on your input validation, you might have a SQL injection vulnerability here.